# Creating Rating Circles using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create Rating circles like:-

[image]

I have tried many techniques like circle within circle, or circle at the top of each other with different `z-index` and `width` in `%`. But I'm having no luck.

What will be the best way to implement this in CSS or JavaScript with using any image.

Comment: Can you show us a bit of code?

Comment: try this http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/jquery_quickie_colourful_rating_system_with_css3.html here is the demo http://demo.marcofolio.net/colourful_rating_system/

Comment: You can create a png image with 5 transparent holes. Than another div in the background where you can adjust the its width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By way of a starting point, have a look at:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r8V6/2/)

HTML

```
<div class='circle'></div>
<div class='circle25'></div>
<div class='circle50'></div>
<div class='circle75'></div>
<div class='circle100'></div>
```

CSS

```
div[class^=circle] {
    background:white;
    border-radius:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
div[class^=circle]:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    background:orange;
}
div.circle25:after {
    width:25%;
}
div.circle50:after {
    width:50%;
}
div.circle75:after {
    width:75%;
}
div.circle100:after {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to do it vice versa, i.e. make the `after` part orange to avoid artifacts on the border.